FCC maps of radio station coverage?
Are there any FCC maps of AM, FM, and TV station coverage on ArcGIS?

I don't know about on ArcGIS, but you can:

Do an AM query, FM query, or TV query with the FCC.
Click the "Links & Maps" tab.
Click the "Service Contour on Open Street Map or USGS Map"

KML files can be downloaded.
Example:

